# ¿Puedo hacer que los números escritos después del signo "+" sea el valor de n2?

Tags: vb.net, vba, vb

Soy principiante y necesito resolver una duda en VB. Estoy realizando una calculadora donde n1 es el primer valor y n2 el segundo, lo que quiero es que en el textbox aparezca así "10 + 10" o sea concatenado, pero mi duda es si puedo hacer que el número escrito después del signo "+" sea el valor de n2. Muchas gracias de antemano.

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Comment: Bienvenido a [es.so]! Lee [ask] y [¿sobre qué temas puedo preguntar aquí?](http://es.stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic) para aprender a realizar una buena pregunta. Un detalle importante es siempre poner el código como texto, no como una captura. En cuanto a tu pregunta, no entiendo muy bien. Si pones `txtprin.Text = n1 & "+" & n2`, debe darte el resultado esperado.

Answer (score 0):

Sería importante mantener un espacio entre los números y el operador por ejemplo txtprin.Text = "10 + 10"

```
Dim val() As String
val = txtprin.Text.Split(" ")
Dim n1  As Integer = Convert.toInt16(val(0))
Dim n2 As Integer = Convert.toInt16(val(2))
Dim op As String = val(1)
Dim res As Integer = 0
Select Case op
    Case "+"
        res = n1 + n2
    Case "-"
        res = n1 - n2
    Case "*"
        res = n1 * n2
    Case "/"
        res = n1 / n2
End Select
```